# Kernel of multiplication-by-n map between abelian varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

My question is about Remark 7.3 from Milne's note on abelian varieties: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/av.html (ver. 2.0).

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over a field $k$; Let $A_n(k):=\ker([n]:A(k)\to A(k))$ be the kernel of the multiplication-by-$n$ map (contained in the $k$-points of $A$). Assume $\text{char}(k)\nmid n$ so that the morphism $[n]:A\to A$ is finite étale.

Milne says then: If $k$ is *separably closed*, then $\#A_n(k)=\deg([n])$. I want to know

1. How to deduce the above claim.
2. An example where $\#A_n(k)\neq \deg([n])$ if we drop the assumption on $k$.

Comment: $k(A[n])/k$ is separable thus $k(A[n])=k$, $k(A/A[n])$ is the subfield of $k(A)$ fixed by $ \{ (f\mapsto f(a+.)), a\in A[n]\}$ which must be the Galois group of the Galois extension $k(A)/k(A/A[n])$, thus $\deg([n])=[k(A):k(A/A[n])]=|Gal(k(A)/k(A/A[n]))|=|A[n]|$

Comment: For 2. you can look into supersingular elliptic curves, these provide counterexamples for $dim(A)=1$.